# Upstart conf to require syslog

Tags: upstart

Translating SysV to Upstart I want to turn this to Upstart:

```
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
```

I'm stuck with translating $syslog..

```
start on (runlevel [2345] and started remote-filesystem and ???)
```

What's the recommended start on for this approach.

Comment: "rsyslog" or whatever your system's syslog daemon is.

Comment: Is there a common name that will work on both Centos6 and Ubuntu(s)?

Comment: Don't think so. It's `rsyslogd` for centos and `rsyslog` for Ubuntu.